# String similarity TF-IDF Bag of words or Word2vec

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, word2vec, sentence-similarity

I am trying to create an application that computes the similarity between 2 strings.
The strings are not long. 3 Sentences long at maximum.
I did some research and I came across some possible solution paths.

First one use bag of words: count words and compare the 2 produced vectors ( cosine similarity)

The second use TF-IDF and compare produced vectors.

The third is use word2vec and compare vectors.

Now for the questions.

Performance wise is word2vec performance better that TF-IDF for short sentences?

What is the best way to train word2vec model? Should I use a large amount of text ( wikipedia dump for example) or train it using just the sentences that are being compared.

How to get sentence similarity from word2vec. should I average the words in each sentence or is there a better solution?

Comment: Several things here. It is not a programming question so you should not ask it here, it will be flagged as off topic.

I don't know about performance comparison. But regarding word2vec, you could use it as an embedding matrix for your words, then have an recurrent net produce a representation of the sentence. This may be overshooting your problem, but these model are made to build  a representation of sequences, just like you want to do. However you would need a train set to learn the representation. Otherwise may be you can train this model in an unsupervised way?

Comment: I am not good with neural networks could you please provide a link to an example for using word2vec and a recurrent net to produce a representation of the sentence. For the training set how much data should it have. i don't have a large dataset to use at the moment. Any ideas how to do it in an unsupervised way. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With good train data, word2vec must have better performance. (I got good results from it)
- You must have large amount of data for good model. The best way is using pre-trained data if you are working on English. There are good models in [this link](https://github.com/3Top/word2vec-api) you can use. Google News pre-trained model is working perfect as I know.
- It is common to use Average of words in part of text like sentence. The better way can be Weighted Average like tf-idf weighting average. Also there is a hot research on semantic textual similarity you can follow it from it's [Wiki Page](http://ixa2.si.ehu.es/stswiki/index.php/Main_Page)